# Software to generate automatic subtitles? (film)

Tags: video, automation, video-editing

I am new in the video subtitle domain, and I found out that it was maybe possible to accelerate the process of subtitle editing by using softwares able to automaticly generate subtitles with timecode.

I found another post "How to create automatic subtitles" but all the links are passed out !
So I am here with no solution.

Youtube seems to be able to generate automatique subtitles but it doesn't process every vidéo (specialy not long film videos).

The type of video I need to word on will usually be long feature film from 60 min to 200min lenght.

Do you know any software that will work on long videos?

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Please note this site is about recommending *software,* not assets or [resources](//meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/2470/185) like [howtos](https://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/882/185), [manuals/tutorials](//meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/1258/185), etc. If you're looking for software, please see [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](https://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185), and then [edit] your question accordingly. Especially missing: OS, price limit, features required, formats.

Comment: @Izzy - I find the question interesting, and have attempted to bring the question into better focus.  Does it fit the site better now?

Comment: @aparente001 that was why I didn't put it on hold: it can easily be made fitting (I just updated the title as well). // **Jake:** We'd need to know what OS you are on, and what your price limit is. If it's important for you, please also mention the subtitle format(s) you need supported.